# discord.py warnings command mongodb

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a command that shows the warns a user has through mongodb and I'm getting this error with the current code I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 199, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: index 'reason' cannot be applied to Cursor instances
```

Here's my code:

```
@client.hybrid_command(name = "warnings", with_app_command=True, description="View the warnings of a member", aliases=["punishments"])
@commands.is_owner()
async def warnings(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.reply("A Member is required")
    else:
        check = warndb.warn_logs.find({"user_id": member.id})
        if check is None:
            await ctx.reply("This user has no warns")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title=f"{member.name}'s warnings")
            embed.add_field(name=f"{check['reason']}", value=f"<@{check['moderator_id']}>", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

For extra info: I'm trying to make it show **ALL** the warnings a user has and put it in embed fields

Answer (score 0):

##### Problem

`collection.find()` returns an iterable of all the found documents. `find_one()` returns one.

##### Solution

Assuming you create a document for every warning, and not 1 document per user with all the warnings in some attribute, you can loop through all occurrences of `collection.find()` as it is returns a `Cursor` object which is iterable.

##### Other Problems

- You should use `is None`, not `== None`, in your first if statement.

#### Code

```py
@client.hybrid_command(name = "warnings", with_app_command=True, description="View the warnings of a member", aliases=["punishments"])
@commands.is_owner()
async def warnings(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.reply("A Member is required")
    else:
        warnings = warndb.warn_logs.find({"user_id": member.id})
        if warnings is None:
            await ctx.reply("This user has no warns")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title=f"{member.name}'s warnings")
            for warning in warnings:
                embed.add_field(name=f"{warning['reason']}", value=f"<@{warning['moderator_id']}>", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```